# Book recommendation to study topics of Linear Programming for self study

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming, book-recommendation

I need some reference book suitable for self-study with many solved examples and solutions preferably for exercise questions for following study. ***Need basic honours undergraduate level  text*** , suitable for self study

**Linear Programming: Linear programming problems, basic solution, basic feasible solution and optimal solution; Graphical method and simplex method of solutions; Duality. Transportation and assignment problems.***

I have a background of Linear Algebra, Calculus (single and multi-variable), some real analysis and group theory. For comparison, I've read Stephen Abbott's [Understanding Analysis](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781493927111) and Fraleigh's [A First Course in Abstract Algebra](https://www.abebooks.com/9780201763904/First-Course-Abstract-Algebra-7th-0201763907/plp).

Comment: these are from separate courses

Comment: Ok done...………...

Comment: What background do you have in mathematics?  Strong familiarity with linear algebra would affect a recommendation about how to self-study linear programming.

Comment: @hardmath I have background of Linear Algebra, Caluclus Single, multivariable, some real analysis and group theory

Comment: I suggest adding the title and author of a similar book you successfully used to self-study another topic in mathematics.

Comment: @hardmath I used Stephen Abbot 's understandning analysis, Fraleigh's "Introduction to abstract algebra". etc etc

Comment: I've added the books that I think you referenced to the body of the Question.  Please review my edit to check that I've not unintentionally mistaken your meaning (and rollback the edit if necessary).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks but I wonder when will I get response from viewers

Comment: I recommend you Hillier Operational Research 9th edition. All the topics you mention are covered in that book. This topics in particular _simplex method of solutions; Duality. Transportation and assignment problems_ are very well explained with at least one example.

Comment: The reason of why I recommend specifically 9th ed. It's because there exist a manual solution for 90% of the exercises proposed by Hillier :) and believe me, it can help you **a lot**

Comment: If you could understand _Fraleigh's_, course in group theory, real analysis, then there is no doubt that you'll also understand by yourself the book I mention

Comment: @user441848 Thanks for book. I need tons of examples and interested in moderate leveldifficulty questions and not very hard. I will check it out

Comment: good. If you have questions or doubts about an exercise you can ask here https://or.stackexchange.com/questions instead of math.stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Question calls for a book suitable for self-study of linear programming "with many solved examples and solutions".  This topic is usually blended with others in a mathematics course, and I'm a little doubtful about what "basic honours undergraduate level text" should mean in this context.

What comes to mind as an inexpensive text targeted at self-study is Schaum's Outline Series Operations Research (2nd edition) by Bronson and Naadimuthu.  After the first introductory chapter on Mathematical Programming, there follow four chapters which cover all the fundamental aspects of formulating and solving linear programs.  The book boasts "310 fully solved problems" and "[h]undreds of practice problems" (whose answers are given in the final "Answers to Supplementary Problems" section), a proportional number of which are for later chapters (four on Integer Programming, three on Nonlinear Programming, etc.).

One is likely to find a new copy of this at a local bookstore for about $20 US, and more cheaply in used bookstores or online.  If one were interested in pursuing a study (after this initial foray) of *proofs* connected to the simplex algorithm and its variants, I'd be apt to consider texts for algorithms and complexity theory.  Certainly there is interesting material from late 20th century investigations, and much of this can be gleaned from online publications once the basics are mastered.